# regex pattern needed to replace

Tags: javascript, regex

I am not too good at regular expressions so need some help from the community. any help is appreciated.
I have a string as below

```
String str= "accountnumber,10000,accountname,Nachiket,balance,null,age,38"
```

I need a regex pattern to replace ,10000, or ,Nachiket, or ,null,
the string should look something similar

```
String str= "accountnumber,10000\naccountname,Nachiket\nbalance,null\nage,38"
```

This is my requirement. I have tried below pattern

```
String str=str.replace(",/[^a-z0-9-]/,",',/[^a-z0-9-]//n')
```

Thanks,
Nachiket

Comment: k.. I have made an attempt as below String str=str.replace(",/[^a-z0-9-]/,",',/[^a-z0-9-]//n')

Comment: Did any of the posted answer work out for you?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to group values like `accountnumber,10000` and `accountname,Nachiket` etc. In that case, you can just search for two words and two comma patterns. Something like this:-

`(.*?),(.*?),`

Regex101 Sample - https://regex101.com/r/dEGs9c/1

And here is the JavaScript implementation

```js
let str = "accountnumber,10000,accountname,Nachiket,balance,null,age,38"
let pattern = /(.*?),(.*?),/g

let output = str.replace(pattern, (match)=> {
    // match will be => accountnumber,10000, => accountname,Nachiket, etc
    // use slice to remove the last character (comma)
   return match.slice(0, -1) + "\n"
})

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using replace, you can match any char except a comma, followed by an optional part that matches a comma and again any char except a comma.

If you don't want to cross lines, you can use `\n` in the negated character class, or if you don't want to match spaces, you can use `[^,\s]+`

```
[^,\n]+(?:,[^,\n]+)?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0WDWdt/1)

```js
const regex = /[^,\n]+(?:,[^,\n]+)?/g;
[
  "accountnumber,10000,accountname,Nachiket,balance,null,age,38",
  "test1",
  "test2,test2",
  "test3,test3,test3"
].forEach(s => console.log(s.match(regex)));
```